# tmux question - why can user "pi" attach to a tmux session, but not the other user?

Tags: raspbian

My second user "robert" cannot attach to a tmux session, even when I used `sudo`. I type: `sudo tmux attach -t ruby` and I get the output of `no current session`. If I type `tmux ls`, I get `no server running on /tmp/tmux-1001/default`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to use `tmux -S /tmp/tmux-1000/default attach -t ruby`. The [`-S`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/tmux) option directs the command to use the server socket created by the UID 1000 (pi) rather than look for server sockets for UID 1001 (robert).

Comment: Yes, that worked perfectly. I still had to use sudo, but I was able to attach. Thank you, that was great.